# Main Net RPC IP

Tags: ganache, blockchain-fork, mainnet

I am trying to fork Ethereum Main Net via Ganache. In order to do this, I need The URL of the existing chain's RPC server. Nevertheless, I can't find such URL anywhere. Can anybody suggest such URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to fork the mainnet you obviously need some place to fork it *from*. So you need access to a node which uses the mainnet and you can then connect to it with RPC.

You can either run your own node and wait for it to synchronize, or use a public (free) node service such as Infura or Alchemy.